# OOP concept of protected members of a class

Tags: c#

I am reviving OOP concepts such as protected etc. using C#.
Here is the problem:

```
// Demonstrate protected. 

using System;

class B
{
    protected int i, j; // private to B, but accessible by D 

    public void Set(int a, int b)
    {
        i = a;
        j = b;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " " + j);
    }
}

class D : B
{
    int k; // private 

    // D can access B's i and j 
    public void Setk()
    {
        k = i * j;
    }

    public void Showk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(k);
    }
}

class E : D 
{   //private
    int l;
    public void Setl() 
    {
        //using protected i,j
        l = i * j;
    }

    public void Showl()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(l);
    }
}

class ProtectedDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        D ob = new D();
        E e = new E();
        ob.Set(2, 3); // OK, known to D 
        ob.Show();    // OK, known to D 

        ob.Setk();  // OK, part of D 
        ob.Showk(); // OK, part of D

        e.Setl();
        e.Showl();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Why is e.Showl() showing '0' then it should be 6???

Comment: `ob.Showl();` if you wanted 6 ;)

Comment: Because you are forgetting the difference between `static` and non-`static`.

Comment: But according to:"Likepublicand private,protectedstatus stays with a member no matter how many 
layers of inheritance are involved. Therefore, when a derived class is used as a base class for 
another derived class, any protected member of the initial base class that is inherited by the 
first derived class is also inherited as protected by a second derived class"   I should get 6 out of e.showl() ....@LearningNeverStops

Comment: would u plz specify @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: Recommend reading the free book `C# Yellow Book` by Rob Milles.  It offers a great introduction into access modifiers, statics, and basic OOP using C#: http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

Comment: I am already following C# 3.0 The Complete Reference

Comment: It would be better if someone dig the 'static' issue here as i am not using it here at all

Answer (score 4):

Inheriting a member means a derived class will *have* this member, not that it will share its value with all parents and descendants (unless the member is static).

At `E e = new E();` you initialize a **new instance** of `E`, which inherits from `D` and `B` but doesn't automagically share the field values of other instances. They would share those if these fields `i` and `j` were static.

When you do this:

```
E e = new E();
e.Set(21, 2);
e.Setl();
e.Showl();
```

The response will be `42`.

Comment: "inherit" is probably not the best choice of word here; an instance of `E` does indeed inherit fields, it simply doesn't share them.

Comment: But according to C # 3.0 The Completer reference:"Likepublicand private,protectedstatus stays with a member no matter how many layers of inheritance are involved. Therefore, when a derived class is used as a base class for another derived class, any protected member of the initial base class that is inherited by the first derived class is also inherited as protected by a second derived class"

Comment: Yes, the class `E` **inherits** the protected fields `i` and `j`, but since those fields are not `static`, each **instance** of either `B`, `D` and `E` will have their own values for those fields.

Answer (score 3):

`E` is a completely different instance than `ob`, although `E` derives from `D` it has no relationship with another *instance* of `D`.

If you want the result of `Show` to be 6 then you need to call `Set(2, 3)` on `E` i.e.

```
e.Set(2, 3);
e.Setl();
e.Showl();
```

Answer (score 0):

What really does your code:

```
D ob = new D(); // create D; i,j,k =0 (default value for int in c#)
E e = new E();  // create E; i,j,k,l =0
ob.Set(2, 3); // ob.i = 2, ob.j = 3 ; e.i and e.j still 0
ob.Show();    // 2 3

ob.Setk();  // ob.k=6 
ob.Showk(); // show 6
e.Setl();  //e.l = e.i* e.j  thus e.l=0*0=0
e.Showl(); //show 0
Console.ReadKey();
```

Values of object E are stored  in another place than  values of object D, even if they have the same name. If you want D.i and E.i to have the same value, use static keyword.

Secondly, initialize variables, that's a good practice in all cases, especially you cannot predict the proper outcome of your integers.

Protected keyword means accessible for subclass in a calling way. It does not mean that a subclass object have the same storage for variables.